# How to turn this layout into html/css?

Tags: html, css

my partner design agency sent me a layout to be turned into html/css.
You can see a bit of that layout here, the navigation bar at the top is the only neccessary.

[image]

My problem now is actually, i'm not sure, how to realize that layout in html/css, as that "bend" in the green navigation bar isn't in the middle of the page. The layout should be flexible, so i don't even want to use one big image (2500x75 px) including the bend and center it. It would be nicer to have two elements, one holding the logo starting from the left, the other holding the navigation links starting from the right.

How would you realize that?

Comment: What part are you stuck with? Without trying to be dismissive, this doesn't *seem* that difficult; so I'm not sure if I'm perhaps missing a detail, somewhere.

Comment: You can repeat the background, for example the thicker and thinner line and only cut the bumpy part of the nav.

Comment: That blurry image is bothering my eyes =/

Comment: This is why the Designer should ALWAYS know HOW to build this in CSS.

Comment: I edited the image in the question.  Much better for my eyes now.

Comment: Why in the world is this getting voted up?!?!?! This "question" is a wish list and no effort has been made by the OP

Comment: @Paul I think this is a common beginner question on how to center html/css headers. And, because it's christmas today.

Comment: I wish I could favorite Max Gherkins' answer, but had to favorite the question instead.

Answer (score 6):

You could do something with some rotated `<div>`, maybe like this:

```
<div class="full"></div>
<div class="half">
    <div class="corner"></div>
</div>​
```

```css
.full{
    height: 40px;
    background: lightgreen;
}
.half{
    width: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    background: lightgreen;
}
.corner{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: -20px;
    background: lightgreen;   
}
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FWb8L/2/)**

**Improved demo using css skew: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kvwwe/)**    ​

Comment: and ofcourse, say goodbye to older browsers :) better solution is to put some png in corner.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović: It's OK to reserve enhancements for modern browsers and let the older ones have a degraded experience, as long as functionality and usability isn't affected.

Comment: let's make that a jpg for full IE6- support :)

Comment: Very cool Max. I updated for -moz- and -o- specific support: http://jsfiddle.net/FWb8L/1/

Comment: that's an great idea, but as i wrote below, i want the bend to be positioned about 300 pixels left of the middle of the header. how would you do that?

Comment: c'mon, chris, just set width that you need in .half

Comment: or just add `margin-left: -300px;` to .half

Comment: would be an idea, but about different screen resolutions? setting a fixed width to .half would result in a creepy displaced layout at another resolution, doesn't it? i think, a better solution for me will be to translate .half using a negative left property.

Comment: He's sayed "The layout should be flexible" so margins in pixels can ruin felxible deign.